# Rails: Block building/create for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple e-commerce application with models `User` and `Order`. The model `Order` has a column status indicating the status of the order where an order with `status = 0` is a cart. In practice, `User` can have many `Order`s. a User can have only one cart though. To achieve this functionality, I have the following models. `order.rb`:

```
STATUS_VALUES = { 'CART' => 0, 'CONFIRMED' => 1,'DELIVERED' => 2}
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :order_items, inverse_of: :order
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_items
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  has_many :photos
  has_many :orders
  has_one :cart
end
```

And in addition I have created the model `Cart`, where cart.rb:

```
class Cart < Order
  self.table_name = "orders"
  default_scope { where("orders.status = 0") }  
end
```

Through this implementation, I'm able to:
1. For User to allow only building one cart at a time. Two successive `user.build_cart` won't work. This is perfect, exactly what I wanted. My problem though is that you can user.orders.build(status: 0) will allows work no matter how many carts I already have. 
My aim is to block creating orders so that building carts is only allowed. A cart can then be updated to a non-cart through changing the status column. How can I do this in Rails?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to build cart is to save them in session variables not in databases. U can find solutions by doing quick search.

Comment: But then logging out and logging back in is going to result in rebuilding the cart, right?

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer. Telling someone to search doesn't provide any value.

Comment: @MaartenDev u definitely right. This was my first reaction hear, so I did not knew their was comment and answer.

Comment: @mrateb non because session variables are stored in the browser of the user.

Comment: I don't think this answer will help me though honestly :/
I need to know in the general case how to block a parent class from creating objects :)